# Relative pathing via scheduled path

Tags: r, task, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a batch that can run my R script through windows Task Scheduler. I have this R project running where I can run my setup code - which applies packages and sources the rest of the script files:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\R-4.0.2\bin\Rscript.exe" "location of startupscript.r"
```

As soon as I get to a source command, where I have used relative pathing, with the path being

```
source("./Scripts/script to source 1.R")
```

I get an error that this file is not found, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try printing the working directory with getwd() or here::here() to see where R thinks it is.

Comment: Ah i see, when run through cmd i get something different when i run getwd(), i have implemented setwd and should work now - thanks